# How to do a sorted search using Apache Directory API

Tags: java, openldap, apache-directory

I am using the Apache Directory API to query an OpenLDAP server. I think this code should return the results sorted by `sn` but they are returned in random order.

```
    SearchRequest req = new SearchRequestImpl();
    req.setScope(SearchScope.ONELEVEL);
    req.addAttributes("*");
    req.setTimeLimit(0);
    req.setBase(searchDn);
    req.setFilter("(objectclass=posixAccount)");

    SortRequest sortRequest = new SortRequestControlImpl();
    sortRequest.addSortKey(new SortKey("sn"));
    req.addControl(sortRequest);

    try (EntryCursor cursor = new EntryCursorImpl(connection.search(req))) {        
        for (Entry entry : cursor) {
            System.out.println("sn: " + entry.get("sn").getString());                
        }
    }
```

The output of this code from the data in my test LDAP Server is:

```
sn: Trainee 
sn: Admin 
sn: User 
sn: Supervisor 
sn: Supervisor
```

I based the code on this Integration test https://github.com/apache/directory-server/blob/master/server-integ/src/test/java/org/apache/directory/server/operations/search/SortedSearchIT.java and I can't see what I have done wrong.

Can anyone offer any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the returned list? Just so I can see what this is producing

Comment: I've updated the question with the output from my test server. Also the order doesn't change if I do call `sk.setReverseOrder( true );` on the SortKey, so I think the sorting is just being ignored.

Comment: Have you tried **without** wrapping the search result in a EntryCursorImpl?

Comment: I just tried this - same result
    `try (SearchCursor cursor = connection.search(req)) {
            SearchResultEntry se = (SearchResultEntry) cursor.get();
            Entry entry = se.getEntry();
            System.out.println("sn: " + entry.get("sn").getString());
        }`

Comment: Yes. Same result?

Comment: Yes same result :(

Comment: Then I have no idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, I had to do two things to get this to work.

First add sssvlv support to my OpenLDAP server

This is the ldif

```
dn: cn=module{0}, cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: sssvlv.la

dn: olcOverlay=sssvlv,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcSssVlvConfig
olcSssVlvMax: 10
olcSssVlvMaxKeys: 5
```

Then I had to specify the Matching Rule ID for the sort key

```
SortKey sk = new SortKey( "sn", SchemaConstants.NUMERIC_STRING_ORDERING_MATCH_MR_OID);
```

Hopefully this will help someone!